# What is the correct command line format for ffmpeg in this case

Tags: ffmpeg

I apologise if this is a duplicate. I have used ffmpeg in the past to convert .pngs to .mp4 but now I am using it on my own files and I am not sure of the format it should have.
I have some files with the following naming convention:

```
   ./profiles_0.png
   ./profiles_40.png
   ...
   ./profiles_400.png
```

The number of files I have varies, i.e. it isn't always 400 and the interval isn't always going to be 40. I have tried the following:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1 -i profiles_%d0.png -r 6 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

but that only captures one of the images. Is there a flexible format in the 'profiles_%d0.png"  argument that captures all of the files in that directory regardless of the number of characters following the underscore or does it require that I change my naming convention?

Cheers for any help,
A

Comment: Files have to be continuously numbered without breaks. I suggest you create symlinks to your images which are smoothly numbered.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have the images of interest in your folder it's easy. You can use a command similar to yours, examples are given in this [other question](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/7300/how-to-get-ffmpeg-to-join-non-sequential-image-files-skip-by-3s). Basically you can match  the files with a wildcard operator and their extension, `*.png` in that case.
It could look like this:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -pattern_type glob -i '*.png' out.avi
```

> This is only selectable if libavformat was compiled with globbing
> support.

According to [FFmpeg's documentation on the image2 demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#toc-image2-1).

If you have other files with other numbering or if you have a sequence of files and want to select a subsequence, I see no way to do it automatically but you can specify such sequence. You'll still need to use `glob`, you can get help on the use of globs in FFmpeg [there](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/FFMPEG_An_Intermediate_Guide/image_sequence#Not_numbered_or_no_regular_pattern) and more information on glob programming [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)).